# How to test function with React Testing Library

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test this function with React Testing Library this error

```
export default function capitalizeFirstLetter(string: string) 
{
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1); 
}
```

but I got

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charAt')
```

Comment: In your test function where you call this you pass nothing perhaps or `undefined` value. Can you show how you test it?

Comment: Given you're using TypeScript, how did the compiler let you do `capitalizeFirstLetter()`? Is that actually a realistic case to deal with (and if so what _should_ the behaviour be)? And given that this is a vanilla JS function, what relevance does React/Testing Library have? Give a [mre] of your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem I see is that your function will fail when `empty/null/undefined` value is passed and you need a guard for that. And that is why you need a test for.

As an example, I'd test this function as follows

```js
// Should be in another file
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string: string) {
  if (!string) return '';

  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

describe('capitalizeFirstLetter', () => {
  it('should return "Hello"', () => {
    expect(capitalizeFirstLetter('hello')).toBe('Hello');
  });

  it('should return "Hi"', () => {
    expect(capitalizeFirstLetter('Hi')).toBe('Hi');
  });

  it('should not fail when undefined/null or empty value is passed', () => {
    expect(capitalizeFirstLetter(undefined)).toBe('');
    expect(capitalizeFirstLetter(null)).toBe('');
    expect(capitalizeFirstLetter('')).toBe('');
  });
});
```

Or you can use [describe.each](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describeeachtablename-fn-timeout) with the list of payloads.